# Terminate a while loop with multiple conditions in a bash script file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I tried everything, but I still can't get the while loop to stop based on the following condition:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
counter=1

breakCond=$(tail -n 1 /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Res/Com_Output.txt|sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/')
    
cd /home/a/Desktop/cliquer-1.21
rm /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Res/Com_Output.txt
clear

Mu=$(head -1 /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Mu.txt)
while [[ $counter -le 97 && $breakCond -ne $Mu ]]
do
#echo $counter| tee -a outErr.txt

    ./cl -u /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/G_$counter.txt &> /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Res/calculated_$counter.txt
#echo -e "calculated_$counter.txt \n"

    output=$(tail -1 /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Res/calculated_$counter.txt)

    echo $output>>/home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Res/Com_Output.txt

    ((counter++))

    breakCond=$(tail -n 1 /home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes/Res/Com_Output.txt|sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/')
done
```

The second condition in my while loop does not work. I'm reading two values from txt files ("breakCond" and "Mu") and attempting to compare them.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There is no way to know what goes wrong with what you gave here.

Comment: If I put `counter=98` and `breakCond=$((Mu+1))` inside the loop, it exits after the first iteration. Without knowing what you have inside the loop, I have no idea why it doesn't work for you (or even why you expect it to exit). You really need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: @SimonDoppler I have updated my code.

Comment: Your tags and title say "Bash script" but your shebang says `#!/bin/sh`. Please review [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: That's neither minimal nor reproducible -- nobody but you can try this out without a lot of other things (`./cl`, a number of files, etc) that shouldn't be needed to show the problem. If you replace the current stuff that sets `breakCond` with just `breakCond=$((Mu+1))`, does it exit after 97 iterations?

Comment: @GordonDavisson when I use value insted of Mu it works fine `while [[ $counter -le 97 && $breakCond -ne 17 ]]` but with Mu i get syntax error `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is`

Comment: Could you show us exactly what the first and last line are of those respective files which you build `breakCond` and `Mu` on. On top of that, could you also show us the values of `breakCond` and `Mu`.

Comment: @kvantour Mu file contains only a number

Comment: @kvantour I also extracted the first number from this file `size=17, weight=17: 2 11 31 42 43 49 63 66 73 79 93 96 103 107 109 112 113` which is 17 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Bash features, you need to make sure the script is executed by Bash.  The precise location of Bash can vary, so I'll use `env` for portability here; but probably, you might want to hardcode e.g. `#!/bin/bash` to avoid this indirection.

Bash has built-in facilities for looping a specified number of times.

As a general design, I would remove the hard-coded absolute paths, and perhaps allow the user to override a built-in default. I also took out the apparently completely superfluous `cd` and the user-hostile `clear`.  The current redesign simply assumes that you are running in `/home/a/Desktop/Triple_Graphs/11_nodes` so that you can run it in a different directory with sample data to test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

break_maybe () {
    # sed $!d replaces tail -n 1
    sed -r '$!d;s/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/' "$1"
}

rm -f Res/Com_Output.txt

Mu=$(head -1 Mu.txt)

# {1..97} is Bash-specific
for counter in {1..97}; do
    if [[ $(break_maybe Res/Com_Output.txt) == "$Mu" ]]; then
        break
    fi
    /home/a/Desktop/cliquer-1.21/cl -u "G_$counter.txt" > "Res/calculated_$counter.txt" 2>&1
    tail -n 1 "Res/calculated_$counter.txt"
done >>Res/Com_Output.txt
```

I obviously have no way to test this, but it should at least suggest some ways to refactor this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  this also has the same issue which break condition not working

Comment: For example this works: `if [[ $(break_maybe Res/Com_Output.txt) == "17" ]]`

Comment: but I need to have the Mu as a variable.

Comment: Sounds like your file has some invisible characters, like probably DOS line endings. See also [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) Running with `bash -x` should reveal this.

Comment: `
+ bash -x Mu.txt
+ $'17\r'
Mu.txt: line 1: $'17\r': command not found
`

Comment: Yeah, that `\r` is a DOS carriage return. (But normally you would run your _script_ with `bash -x`, not the text file!)

Comment: I only need to run my script like `bash -x myscript.sh ?`

Comment: That's how you run it with debug tracing enabled; you probably need to spend some time familiarizing yourself with the output.